# How to subtract first and last values in grouped data for all columns in dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a timeseries dataset containing scores on scales of depression, anxiety, and trauma for patients. Data was collected at 6 time points for each patient.

```
mh_data.head(10)
```

```
ID    BDI   GAD   TSQ  age
1     57     9     4    22
1     36     9     4    22
1     37     9     4    22
1     38     7     3    22
1     41     8     3    22
1     39     7     3    22
2     29     14    7    35
2     27     12    6    35
2     27     11    6    35
2     23     11    3    35
```

I want to create a new dataset where each patient has only 1 corresponding value for each of the variables which represents the difference between the first last and recorded data point. So, it will look like this:

```
ID    BDI   GAD   TSQ  age
1     18     2     1    22
2     1      0     2    35
.     .      .     .    .
.     .      .     .    .
.     .      .     .    .
```

I've grouped the data and aggregated by first and last scores:

```
mhs_agg = mhs_data.groupby("ID").agg(['first','last'])
```

How can I proceed or is there a more efficient way of doing this? I also have age which is a variable I don't want to be computing the difference for (as this will come out as 0 for everyone).

I've seen all of the following posts and none of the suggestions seem to work for my specific case.

[How to apply "first" and "last" functions to columns while using group by in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001237/how-to-apply-first-and-last-functions-to-columns-while-using-group-by-in-pan)

[Python/Pandas - Aggregating dataframe with first/last function without grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358385/python-pandas-aggregating-dataframe-with-first-last-function-without-grouping)

[Pandas DataFrame groupby two columns and get first and last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316893/pandas-dataframe-groupby-two-columns-and-get-first-and-last)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
df1 = df[['ID','BDI', 'GAD', 'TSQ']].groupby('ID').agg('first')-df[['ID','BDI', 'GAD', 'TSQ']].groupby('ID').agg('last')
df_final = df1.merge(df[['ID','age']].groupby('ID').agg('first'), on='ID')


    BDI  GAD  TSQ  age
ID
1    18    2    1   22
2     6    3    4   35
```

Second option using lambda to get the first part, then merge

```
df[['ID','BDI', 'GAD', 'TSQ']].groupby('ID', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.groupby('ID').agg('first')-x.groupby('ID').agg('last'))
```

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks for the response. This works just fine, could I incorporate the absolute function to get the absolute difference in this case though?

Comment: I've not used the absolute on difference in dataframes, but assume it could be done. The second option I just added to the answer using lambda might be easier (use absolute around the two agg functions)

Comment: Yep that works just fine thanks. One last question, the "id" columns is no longer being counted as column. So, when I run df.shape I get 1327 rows, which corresponds to the number of distinct IDs/patients; however, I only get 4 columns. I tried running .reset_index().set_index("id), but this didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: should just be .reset_index(), your code is resetting the index then setting back to 'id'

Comment: I tried running df_final.reset_index(), am I supposed to be using it elsewhere?

Comment: the nuances of pandas....you can tack reset_index() at the end of the second when df_final is created OR df_final.reset_index(inplace=True) OR df_final = df_final.reset_index()

Answer (score 3):

You can pass arbitrary functions into `.agg()`. When you do this, your function receives each pandas series 1 at a time, already filtered down to an individual "group".

I'd probably do the whole calculation as one function instead of multiple separate steps.

```py
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
     'b': [0, 2, 5, 2, 4, 8],
     'c': [5, 8, 1, 4, 2, 1]})

def diff_calc(x):
    x1 = x[:1].values # Get first value
    x2 = x[-1:].values # Get last value
    
    return abs(x1 - x2)

my_data.groupby('id').agg(diff_calc)
```

### Input

| id | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 |

### Output

| id | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 |

ps: You may want to use `.reset_index()` at the end as pandas groupBy is a bit weird, and that may have been the original issue you were running into.

Comment: Hey Tyler, thanks for the response. But, in this case then I would just be calculating the difference in the first and last value for each column not aggregated by an ID or some other unique identifier, right?

Comment: In my example above, the diff_calc gets called 4 times with these inputs: [0, 2, 5], [2, 4, 8], [5, 8, 1], [4, 2, 1].  

Let me know if I missed something in the requirements ... but I think that would be aggregating for each value of "id"?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I must've missed it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[-1])
```